# variation of laplacian on a compact riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, laplacian, compact-manifolds

I have a problem with a part of the proof in the article "prescribing curvature, Kazdan-Warner" of Lemma 3.2. In this lemma is required to compute the variation of the Laplacian operator, the authors say that 
$$\Delta'u=\frac{d}{dt}\Delta_{g_t}u|_{t=0}=-h^{ij}u_{,ij}+\bigg{(}\frac{1}{2}h^{i,j}_{i}-h^{ij}_{,i}\bigg{)}u_{,j}$$
$$k'=\frac{d}{dt}k_{g_t}|_{t=0}=-\Delta h^i_i+h^{ij}_{,ij}-h^{ij}Ric(g)^i_j$$
where $g_t=g-th$. Did someone do this calculations?
 I don't understand very well the tensor calculus, if it is possible, could you write it without this notation? 
Thanks.

Comment: The proof for the formulas as you wrote them is to first compute the first variation of the Christoffel symbols, then use the formulas for the scalar curvature and Laplacian in terms of Christoffel symbols.  Peter Topping wrote a nice proof without indices in his lecture notes on the Ricci flow, see [here](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseq/topping_RF_mar06.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, that's exactly what I was looking for.